# prove that a point x is on the line perpendicular bisector of segment AB if and only if X.....

Tags: euclidean-geometry

prove that a point x is on the line perpendicular bisector of segment AB if and only if X is the center of a circle through points A and B

I'm unsure how to prove this. I will ask questions is the proof provided I cant understand thank you

Comment: Show us how far have you gotten yourself. It is easier for members to give an answer if they know what you already know and what you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $X$ is the middle point of $AB$, it is obvious. Otherwise, consider two rectangular triangles  $\triangle AMX$ and $\triangle BMX$, where $M$ is the middle point of $AB$. Prove (using congruence) that $X$ is equidistant from $A$ and $B$.